# How to fetch Array keys from PHP in jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and would like to know how I can fetch Array keys from a php file into jQuery.

I have this jQuery code to post input to `file.php` and exexute a query on every keyup.

`file.php` echoes the result with the help of an Array what will look like:

```
echo '<li>'.$row["name"].' '.$row["place"].' '.$row["year"].'</li>';
```

The jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() { //changes are possible when the page has fully loaded
    $('.inp').keyup(function() { //executes keyup function to the field class "inp"
        var inp = $(this).attr('value'); //sets a variable with the value of input from class="inp"
        $.post('ajax/file.php', {inp:inp}, function(data) { //posts that value to file.php as variable inp and executes the function (data) to this 
            $('.result').html(data);  //adds the returned result into HTML content as a first element in the set of class="result" => <li>

            $('.result li').click(function() { //executes click function when clicking li element
                var result_value = $(this).text(); //sets a variable and prepares something as text 
                $('.inp').attr('value', result_value); //fills value attribute of field class "inp" with the variable result_value
                $('.result').html(''); //clears li to ul class to hide the lists of results
            });
        });
    });
});
```

So when I click onto the `li` result it will be converted into text and the value attribute of the input field is filled with that.

To give an example:

```
echo '<li>'.$row["name"].' '.$row["place"].' '.$row["year"].'</li>';
```

will output:

```
<li>ExAmpLE Home 2013</li>
```

So when I click on `li` the new value of the input field is:

> ExAmpLE Home 2013

My question is how can I exlude specific Array keys like `$row["name"]` or `$row["year"]` from converting the result value into text from that click function so that the new value of the input field is:

> ExAmpLE Home

Answer (score 2):

You can use json :

`file.php`

```
json_encode(array('name' => $row["name"], 'place' => $row["place"], 'year' => $row["year"]));
```

In your javascript use jQuery [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function to store your data in the DOM to retrieve it later:

```
$.post('ajax/file.php', {inp:inp}, function(data) {
            $('.result').html(
              $('<li>').text(data.name + ' ' + data.place + ' ' + data.year)
                .data('name', data.name)
                .data('place', data.place)
                .data('year', data.year)
                .click(function() {
                    $('.inp').attr('value', $(this).data('name') + ' ' + $(this).data('place'))
                    $(this).empty();
                })
            );
        }, 'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting the stuff you need into a span should work:

```
echo '<li><span>'.$row["name"].' '.$row["place"].'</span> '.$row["year"].'</li>';
```

I assume you already know how to get at the li element. Then do:

```
var $li= $(this);
var text= $li.find('span').text();
```